# rails console behind proxy: cannot connect

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, macos

I am trying to develop against an API that asks me to connect via HTTPS.
`wget` and `curl` works against the address, but Rails' console complains of an error (ERRNO) when connecting. A subsequently created `rake` task also fails.

I have my .bash_profile setup correctly on my Mac. (For example, RVM and bundle works).

Anyone else experienced this? Thanks.

EDIT to include trace (as per Raghu's suggestion)
I am using the highrise gem (https://github.com/tapajos/highrise)

URL setting is 
`Highrise::Base.site = 'https://your_site.highrisehq.com'`

first few lines of trace is

```
Errno::ECONNREFUSED: Connection refused - connect(2)
    from /Users/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:644:in `initialize'
    from /Users/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:644:in `open'
    from /Users/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:644:in `block in connect'
    from /Users/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/timeout.rb:44:in `timeout'
    from /Users/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/timeout.rb:89:in `timeout'
```

Comment: can you post the stacktrace and provide the api url that you are trying to connect( if you dont mind)?

Comment: What do you mean by 'behind proxy'? Proxies and https can sometimes not get along well.